# SQL group_by query

Tags: sql

I have a table name users. Assume in the table I have the following fields :

User id , UUID1 , UUID2

I am trying to build the following SQL query the will return :
.number of rows including both the same UUID1 and UUID2. not that UUID1 equal UUID2 but just number of row including both (GROUP BY) and in addition the number of rows contains UUID1 or UUID2 (Separately, no grouping).

So I would like to have a table output as followed :
UUID1 , UUID2, Number_of_Rows_Contain_both, Number_Of_Rows_Contains_Only_Only_One

Any idea how can I generate such a query ?

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result.

Comment: Also: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: What have you tried? And, yes, what would the output look like with actual (sample) data?

Answer (score 2):

Hope this is what you are aksing for :

```
select 
user_id,
sum 
(case when uuid1 is not null and uuid2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) both_uuid_avlbl,
sum
(case when uuid1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) uuid1_avlbl,
sum
(case when uuid2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) uuid2_avlbl
from sample group by user_id;
```

Below is the Script DDL i used for the above query :

```
   create table sample as  (user_id number(10),uuid1 number(10),uuid2 number(10));
    Insert into sample (USER_ID,UUID1,UUID2) values (1,2,2);
Insert into sample (USER_ID,UUID1,UUID2) values (2,3,2);
Insert into sample (USER_ID,UUID1,UUID2) values (3,1,1);
Insert into sample (USER_ID,UUID1,UUID2) values (4,1,2);
Insert into sample (USER_ID,UUID1,UUID2) values (5,2,0);
Insert into sample (USER_ID,UUID1,UUID2) values (8,null,2);
Insert into sample (USER_ID,UUID1,UUID2) values (7,null,null);
Insert into sample (USER_ID,UUID1,UUID2) values (6,null,2);
Insert into sample (USER_ID,UUID1,UUID2) values (3,null,1);
Insert into sample (USER_ID,UUID1,UUID2) values (1,3,2);
Insert into sample (USER_ID,UUID1,UUID2) values (1,null,2);
Insert into sample (USER_ID,UUID1,UUID2) values (5,3,0);
Insert into sample (USER_ID,UUID1,UUID2) values (5,3,null);
insert into sample (user_id,uuid1,uuid2) values (5,null,null);
```

I used Oracle 11g.

Comment: May call this approach "Conditional Aggregation"  Though I don't know if user_ID and group by is needed since OP only asked for number of rows and "Separately, no grouping"

Comment: Take out the Grouping if not required.I just added it to make things easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

For your Result you can go for this:

```
    declare @both INT
    declare @a INT
    declare @b INT
    declare @c INT
    select @both = count(*) from users where UUID1  is not null and UUID2 is not null 
    select @a = count(*) from users where UUID1  is not null and UUID2 is  null 
    select @b = count(*) from users where UUID1  is  null and UUID2 is not null 
    select @c = count(*) from users where UUID1  is  null and UUID2 is  null 
    Select @both as BothCount,@a AS UUID1Count,@b AS UUID2Count,@c AS Bothnull
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me put my understanding of your question first;
The tables format is as below;

```
user_id,UUID1, UUID2
1 a a 
2 a b
3 b b
4 b c
5 d c
```

and the output for such an input sample you are looking for is as below;

```
a   1   1
b   1   2
c   0   2
d   0   1
```

A possible solution would be;

```
SELECT UUID, sum(SAME) SAME, sum(DIFFERENT - SAME) DIFFERENT
FROM (
    select a.UUID, 
      case when (a.UUID = t.UUID1 and a.UUID = t.UUID2) THEN 1 else 0 end SAME,
      case when a.UUID = t.UUID1 or a.UUID = t.UUID2 THEN 1 else 0 end DIFFERENT
    from 
    (
        select distinct UUID1 as UUID
        from  THE_TABLE

        UNION

        select distinct UUID2 as UUID
        from  THE_TABLE
    ) a,  THE_TABLE t
) GROUP BY UUID
```

tested with DB2 v 10.5.5